# Performance Of Data Storage Objects

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2008

I have inherited some programming duties from my coleagues(<-spelling), with which I am given a users table structured as such:

```
userID BigInt (1,1)
Username Nvarchar(100)
UserPass Nvarchar(100)
Profile  Nvarchar(max)
```

They have programmed all logic for the username/password, and the client went back to them and stated "We now want user profiles".   Since the client already has control of the db, we are not allowed to mmodify existing storage objects, however, they did give us the new Profile field.

What I am wondering is this:
What would be better for performance...?  Are there any benchmarks anywhere?

```
A)Storing profile data as XML
B)Storing profile data as JSON
C)Storing profile data as a comma-delimited list
D)Other that I have not thought of...maybe store a XML file in the filesystem tied to the userID?
```

for any of the above, I will be typing out and breaking out into objects.   Personally I would say JSON, and I can utilize the JSON.Net library

p.s.   This will be in .Net 4, and SQL 2008 R2 on a Win2k8 R2 server (that is personally theirs, and very powerful)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that both XML And Json are acceptable in this case seen as you are forced to store the profile this way.

I have used XML in the past for this mainly for the structure and readability when looking for related profile properties.

if you are worried about the size of this (id imagine it would be quite small though), store the xml in a compressed state.

Comment: yeah, not real worried about the size, as I'm sure it will vary greatly based on what people will fill in for their profile.   But I have to figure on at least the basic profile info...  phone, email, address(s), maybe some social networking stuff, IM stuff, Avatar, etc...

Comment: sorry, i guess I am concerned about size, since I'm asking about performance...DOH!

Comment: but relative to the amount of times something like a user profile will be hit, size is fairly irrelevant unless:
1.  The size of the xml/json, is huge.
2.  There are 10's of thousands (if not 100s of thousands) of users

If its a web app, id imagine you are hitting the db on login, and caching the user profile ye?

Comment: absolutely right I'll be caching it :)    I'm expecting users to be in the millions...  it's a revamp of an already very popular site with a few million registered users

Comment: i wouldnt be comfortable storing that amount of data in a table in that format, but thats my personal opinion.

Look at compression though and storing the data as base64 instead of xml datatype.

Ive used this before for this case, and in another case of storing datagrid configuration xml per user which can be huge.